# How do i catch React login request?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, authentication

So I made a sign and login up form in react but now I wanna register users in a MongoDB database. What would I use I trying to look up YouTube videos and i see the MERN stack being used, but i cant find a good video show how to implement this.

PS i'm still new to this i'm doing a project learn the full stack of web dev, so I will probably be asking a lot of questions here thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a backend to achieve this. You can develop it yourself or use a service like firebase.

Answer (score 0):

React is your front-end and it's going to send a login and a password to the back-end that is going to answer this request and send the response to your front-end (react).

You need to develop the back-end side. If you know React you must be familiar with Javascript so NodeJS could be a good start for you because you'll use Javascript.

Here is an article that explain how to make a simple nodeJS+express serveur and connect it to react

https://medium.com/@maison.moa/setting-up-an-express-backend-server-for-create-react-app-bc7620b20a61